# Is there a way to cleanup or repair savegames?

Tags: ps3, fallout-new-vegas

We are having issues with crashes in `Fallout: New Vegas` on the PS3.  We tried our savegames on another PS3 and encountered the same problems.  Starting a new game on our PlayStation, or loading the savegame of a friend does not have any crashes.

My girlfriend's savegame does crash very often, more often in open areas. With my own savegame crashes are not that frequent but they do happen.

Since we are very advanced it would be very sad if we had to restart from scratch, also we are frightened that this issue could occur again with any other savegame.

We also tried to delete Fallout and reinstall it along with all updates and DLCs, this did not help.

So my question is:
Is there any way to repair or fix up the savegames of the PS3 Version using a Linux or Windows PC?  (Linux would be preferred, but Windows is also available.)

Comment: Some crashes in FNV is because you have a glitchy item in your inventory.  Have you tried dumping everything you have into a container to see if the crashing stops?

Comment: No did not tried that so far. Will give that a try.

Comment: You aren't going to fix the crashes in New Vegas or Fallout 3 for that matter. The games are amazing, but regardless of what you do you're going to continue experiencing them. I've had 4 playthroughs of FO3 and 3 on New Vegas including all DLC and every time I've played it's been the same. One of those games you have to remember to save very often. Turning off autosave does help a little, but it doesn't fix anything by any means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fallout: New Vegas is [notoriously buggy](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_bugs).  As the game wears on, the chances of you encountering one or more crashing bugs becomes increasingly likely.  The [Fallout Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_bugs) has a long list of things that you can try, but here's just a few of the most relevant ones:

> - Turning the pip-boy radio off and leaving it off seems to help quite a bit. Try it if nothing else seems to help.
> - Crashes often when you near completion of the game. Waiting 73 hours can fix this occasionally by resetting all cells except the one you are in.
> - Crashes or very severe slowdowns are common when the player character reaches the top of a hill or ridge and the landscape and sky beyond become visible. (no known workaround)
> - Equipping the sniper rifle may cause the game to slow down severely and most likely freeze. On the PS3 equipping the sniper rifle can cause the weapon hotkeys to stop functioning, and the game to crash shortly thereafter on attempts to sleep, save, enter a new area, or just walk around the map for a minute or so.
> - Sometimes changing the color of the interface can cause the game to crash or lock up. Keeping the interface Amber may help in avoiding this. (On both the Pip-Boy and Hud)

As far as I know, there's no save file editors for Windows or Linux that can fix the cause of crashes in New Vegas.  In fact, editing your save outside the game is probably *more* likely to cause you crashes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. Typically, 30 minutes into the game it would slow way down, especially if I was to go outside. What I did was go through my PS3's hard drive and delete all old games and game saves, essentially did a general system cleanup.

That helped a little bit. Then I remember getting a patch that really sped things up. I'm sorry but I can't recall which patch it is, and I assume that your game is up to date since you said you deleted it and then repatched it.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the colour of the HUD and the crosshair, and that stopped the crashes for me. I haven't experienced a crash since doing it. I've had a few stutters but nothing major. Before I did this, I noticed that I crashed every time I went near water.